# Button Matrix Code and Wiring

Tags: arduino-uno, button

[image]

Bear with me here, I'm new to arduinos, so what I'm saying might only make sense in my own mind.

I'm trying a button matrix and I not completely sure on my wiring and I have a few questions.

1. Is the diagram correct?
2. I wire D2 to D3 and set them to output and input respectively. In the code I digital write to D2 a HIGH, will D3 then read high?
3. What is the best way to read the state of each button? Is there a Library that can simplify it?

I'm sorry if this is all just confused gibberish.

EDIT: I got the idea from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Sc4MJ8RPM), which explains some of it, but no code. He however uses an arduino micro.

EDIT #2: I realized I wired the buttons incorrectly.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad

Comment: you are using 4 wires to read 4 switches .... you could just use one pin for each switch ..... enable internal pullups on the pin and connect the switch between the pin and ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jot commented to use the [Keypad Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad). Which I got to work using the [tutorial](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/KeypadTutorial). Took a few minutes to set up.